# ViewPager with TextView lag

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, textview, lag

I have a ViewPager with a custom layout. This ViewPager has been created following Google/Android documentation and rules.

This layout contains two images (one small icon and optimized image) and many TextView.

I've noticed that ViewPager lags sliding between pages even without populate data. I mean, I've tried only displaying the layout with empty TextViews and slide still lags.

All resources are saved in the relative drawable folder (drawable-xhdpi, drawable-mdpi etc).

How can I do to reduce lags? It could be a problem related to TextViews?

Comment: are you sure it's not related to image ?

Comment: Uhm, actually I'm using the app icon as image. It's very small image. Just this small image can introduce this kind of lag?

Comment: are you recreating fragments while swiping ?

Comment: @s.milziadi not the app icon for sure. Can you share you ViewPager adapter ?

Comment: @HugoGresse here's my adapter http://pastebin.com/JefTfbY6

Comment: could you provide the layout code? Maybe it takes too long to inflate it

Comment: Try use SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Comment: @Lamorak here you can take a look to the layout http://pastebin.com/exYY3usn

Comment: Now I am pretty sure it takes a long while to inflate it and that is causing the lag. You will need to optimize it and maybe reuse it in your adapter..

Comment: @Lamorak I already tried to optimize it (as much as possible). I can replace the right side of the table (where I have textViews) with a ListView, but I don't know how much it will improve performances. If it will not work should I re-design my app?